# Nutritional data for homemade Greek soy yogurt

Tags: vitamins-and-minerals, soy

I make homemade soy Labneh (AKA Greek yogurt) from soybeans by making soy milk, making yogurt from that milk and then straining out the liquids using a cheesecloth. The only ingredients are soybeans and the starter (probiotics or a previous batch of yogurt).

How would I go about finding approximate nutritional data for this yogurt, such as carbs, protein, fat, calcium etc? I googled but couldn't find any commercial Greek soy yogurt, only dairy ones.

Answer (score 2):

I have been considering your question since you posted, it is a good question.

Typically one would calculate the nutritional value based on the ingredients and add them up, but I am not sure how well such a calculation holds up for your case.

Short of sending it for analysis, I would compare it to SILK plain soy yogurt and call it even.

http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/legumes-and-legume-products/10550/2

From https://www.nutritionvalue.org/SILK_Plain_soy_yogurt_nutritional_value.html

[image]

And of course add in anything else you might add to your finished product.

Comment: Greek yogurt is strained (as OP mentions) after the yogurt-making process to remove some of the water, so it's lower in water than normal "plain" yogurt. The composition of the yogurt depends on that of the milk used, of course. I think that this plain yogurt will be higher in water than OP's. Maybe by measuring the mass (or volume, since 1g of water = 1ml of water) of the lost water they could determine the values using a commercial product like this one as a baseline?

Comment: @Zanna - good idea, it may be more accurate.